# OAuth error on fetching tweets even when I am logged into Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth

I am using the Twitter SearchAPI to get tweets of a user.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40xyzuser
```

Trying the above API in the browser but I get

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Interestingly, I am logged into my Twitter account in the same browser. 
Why does it still give unauthenticated error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticated to the api as application to be able to call api urls. 
You can read more about it in Twitter's documentation:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth